# UPDATING information into MySQL Database but department remains the same for each employee

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my DB for the employees table. When I run and test, every user is coming up as working in Accounting even if they work in another department. Is there something I am missing? I am not receiving any errors either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PHP/HTML

```
    <?php

   //ERROR CHECKING CODE
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');

   require_once("dbconnect.php");
    $id = (isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE empid= '" . $id . "';";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

PHP/HTML

```
 <p>Department</br>
    <select name="department">
      <option <?php if($row['department']==1) {print('selected');}?>value="1">Accounting</option>
      <option <?php if($row['department']==2) {print('selected');} ?>value='2'>Legal</option>
      <option <?php if($row['department']==3) {print('selected');} ?>value='3'>Information Technology</option>
      <option <?php if($row['department']==4) {print('selected');} ?>value='4'>Human Resources</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Is the `empid` column numeric, or is it text?  In your query, you're treating it as text, which might affect the logic of the query.  In any case, you should read up on using prepared statements in PHP.

Comment: Can you show me your update query

Comment: Is it a DOM issue or PHP? Is `selected` present on the element where it should be? Get rid of `mysql_error`, that's not going to help and might break your code. Also you should parameterize your query.

Comment: @user3783243 I will get rid of it and what do you mean by parameterize?

Comment: Use placeholders, `?` in the query instead of the value so the driver handles the value passed to it correctly. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Looking into this now!

Comment: You cannot mix APIs (mysql_ and mysqli_), and given that mysql_ is deprecated, you wouldn't want to. Also, see about prepared and bound queries. At present, you're still open to injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code in action it's hard to say, but at first glance there's this problem: In each `option` tag you're not leaving any space between the closing PHP tag (`?>`) and the `value` property, so when if `$row['department']` matches the correspondent value, the PHP statement will print "selected" but with no space, the HTML will look like this (say `$row['department']` equals 2):

```
<option selectedvalue='2'>Legal</option>
```

which obviously won't select that option. Try adding a space after each closing PHP tag, or print "seleted ", with a space in the end.